# Embed external application inside a Cocoa SplitView

Tags: cocoa, sublimetext2

I would like to have an application under Mac OS X that enables me to have Sublime Text 2 and a terminal (for showing test result, run grunt tasks and so on) in the same fullscreen window. I couldn't find an application whith this behaviour and I think of reproducing it myself with cocoa split view. 
I would like to know if it's possible and, if yes, how can I start implementing it

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new application from 2 other applications. It won't work. However you can use applescript to make it easy for you to position these windows as you want.

As an example I'll use Safari and Terminal as my 2 applications. Open them and place them on the screen as you want them to appear. I opened each window large and positioned them side-by-side. Then I ran this applescript to get their window size and position properties...

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set safariSize to size of window 1
        set safariPosition to position of window 1
    end tell
    tell process "Terminal"
        set terminalSize to size of window 1
        set terminalPosition to position of window 1
    end tell
end tell
return {safariSize, safariPosition, terminalSize, terminalPosition}
```

Then I copy/pasted the result from that script into the "theValues" variable in this script. Now whenever I want I can run this script to recreate those window positions.

```
set theValues to {{1001, 1025}, {0, 22}, {613, 1024}, {1003, 22}}

tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "Terminal" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set size of window 1 to item 1 of theValues
        set position of window 1 to item 2 of theValues
    end tell
    tell process "Terminal"
        set size of window 1 to item 3 of theValues
        set position of window 1 to item 4 of theValues
    end tell
end tell
```

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately, this will not work on fullscreen which is what I want to do. I already have solutions for non-full-screen positioning :)

Comment: Correct, it won't go full screen but you won't be able to do that. This is as close as you can get without writing your own application with the abilities of both those applications. I don't think you want to do that so just live with this close approximation.

Comment: it sounds like OP does want to do that, so I recommend he looks at things like Ace, Cloud9 and GateOne... you can build your own IDE with full terminal and then run your browser window in full-screen mode to maximize real estate. You can also run these on a ChromeBook from a cloud instance. Personally, I prefer just some fullscreen, split-pane tmux sessions running remotely, with a vim/emacs powerful editor in one of the panes...